# C++ use of deleted function std::unique_ptr with Base class

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, unique-ptr

I have a vector or Game objects. I have to compile for c++11

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Game> > games_;
```

Game is the base class, defined like this

```
class Game {

public:

        Game(int id, const std::string& name)
                : id_(id), name_(name){}

        virtual ~Game(); 

        int play(int w);
        virtual void validate() = 0;

        int id_;
        std::string name_;

};
```

The derived class just implements the validate() method.

Now my manager class wants to post a "play game" to a thread pool. Done like this:

```
void Manager::playGames() {


        boost::asio::io_service ioService;

        std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work( new boost::asio::io_service::work(ioService));

        boost::thread_group threadpool; //pool
        std::cout << "will start for " << playthreads_ << " threads and " << getTotalRequests() << "total requests\n";
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < playthreads_; ++i)
                threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));

        for ( std::size_t i=0; i < w_.size(); i++) {

                ioService.post(boost::bind(&Game::play, games_[i], 2));

        }    

        work.reset();
        threadpool.join_all();
        ioService.stop();

}
```

The error is

> ```
> /home/manager.cpp: In member function ‘void Manager::playGames()’:
> /home//manager.cpp:65:74: error: use of deleted function
>  ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)
>  [with _Tp = Game; _Dp = std::default_delete<Game>]’ 
>  ioService.post(boost::bind(&Game::play, games_[i], 2));
>                                                                           ^
> In file included from /opt/5.2/include/c++/5.2.0/memory:81:0,
>                  from /home/manager.hpp:5,
>                  from /home/manager.cpp:1: /opt/5.2/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:356:7: note: declared
> here
>        unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
> ```

Comment: You're somehow requesting a copy of a unique_ptr which is deleted because they're defined as being move only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `boost::bind(&Game::play, games_[i], 2)`, `games_[i]` is copied to bind, but `std::unique_ptr` can't be copied. (It can only be moved, but I think moving it here won't match the requirement.)

You can use `boost::ref` to avoid copy, e.g.

```
ioService.post(boost::bind(&Game::play, boost::ref(games_[i]), 2));
```

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘get_pointer(std::reference_wrapper<std::unique_ptr<Game> >&)’

Comment: compiled with boost::ref

Comment: @cateof Sorry I can't test it with boost, I think you're right. BTW `std::bind` with `std::ref` is fine.